# workRequired built-in field unchanged through Attask API

Tags: api, rest, task, attask

There is a task with status of "New" which I'm trying to set the "Planned Hours" for using the Attask Rest API.  The Object Relationships document shows that "workRequired" Task variable represents planned hours.  The url I use looks like this:

https:///attask/api/task/5339c3d700027c67da8a648bd3a5896e?method=put&workRequired=120

After issuing this put, the task's planned hours does not change from its current value of 0.  What more must I do with the url to have the API changed the workRequired?

Comment: After experimentation, I understand that you must change workRequiredExpression in order to set workRequired.  Passing "4 Hours" to workRequiredExpression through the api results in 4*60 = 240 to show up in the database as workRequired.  Sorry I didn't think of this earlier.  This solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use workRequiredExpression instead of workRequired.  Also, you must have durationType set to A (Calculated Assignment) in order to manipulate Planned Hours.

Comment: Man it's infuriating how oddly that's set up. Thanks for digging into it and figuring it out.